# Office 365 User WhenCreated Date formatting is invalid

Tags: office-365, whencreated

Hi I am trying to create common reporting in .csv files on previously created users and new users.  I am however seem to be having issues with my formatting:
January is now the 47th month!

```
> $user.WhenCreated | Get-date
```

10 January 2012 16:47:49

```
> $user.WhenCreated | Get-date -Format  dd-mm-yyyy-hhmm
```

10-47-2012-0447  # What!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I think I am muddling up my months and minutes? I am fairly flexible on the formatting as long it UK in presentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mm is minutes, you want MM.

`$user.WhenCreated | Get-date -Format  dd-MM-yyyy-hhmm`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx

Comment: @westerdaled, please don't forget to mark this as an answer if it helped you.